# ElasticSearch not joining nodes in AWS Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elasticsearch

I am having issues with making clusters on AWS using ElasticSearch:

Software: 
ES: elasticsearch-1.4.1.zip

AWS-Cloud: elasticsearch-cloud-aws/2.4.1

And that is being run on AWS EC2 Micro instance (Ubuntu 64). Both Instances use same security group with everything open, no restrictions at all
I have created two instances in us-west Oregon (us-west-2b) and I am using this configuration file:

```
{
  "cluster.name": "mycluster",
  "http": {
    "cors.enabled" : true,
    "cors.allow-origin": "*"
},
   "node.name": "LosAngeles-node",
   "node.master": "false",
  "cloud": {
    "aws": {
      "access_key": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "secret_key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "region": "us-west"      
    }
  },
  "discovery": {
    "type": "ec2",
          "ec2" : {
        "groups": "esallaccess"
   },
   "zen": {
       "ping": {
          "multicast": {
             "enabled": "false"
              }
          }
      }
 }
}
```

The LosAngeles node should be a work horse for the cluster, thus node.master = false.
When I start this node it constantly pings and never stops pinging, this is in the log after I start it:

```
...
[2014-11-28 15:18:30,593][TRACE][discovery.ec2            ] [LosAngeles-node] building dynamic  
unicast discovery nodes...

[2014-11-28 15:18:30,593][DEBUG][discovery.ec2            ] [LosAngeles-node] using dynamic   
discovery nodes []

[2014-11-28 15:18:32,170][TRACE][discovery.ec2            ] [LosAngeles-node] building dynamic 
unicast discovery nodes...

[2014-11-28 15:18:32,170][DEBUG][discovery.ec2            ] [LosAngeles-node] using dynamic 
discovery nodes []

[2014-11-28 15:18:32,170][TRACE][discovery.ec2            ] [LosAngeles-node] full ping responses: 
{none}

[2014-11-28 15:18:32,170][DEBUG][discovery.ec2            ] [LosAngeles-node] filtered ping 
responses: (filter_client[true], filter_data[false]) {none}

[2014-11-28 15:18:32,170][TRACE][discovery.ec2            ] [LosAngeles-node] starting to ping
...
enter code here
```

I am thinking this is problem with region. Any help is appreciated.

PS
Master node (NewYork) has the same configuration file with different name and node.master = true

Answer (score 1):

Try to add master node address into the new node configuration.

In elasticsearch.yml
Verify the following parameters:

```
cluster.name: your-cluster-name
node.master: false
node.data: false
discovery.zen.ping.timeout: 3s
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["your-master.dns.domain.com"]
```

If you use multicast, disable it. It doesn't work in AWS EC2
For any case check your Security Group.

Answer (score 1):

It is required to allow your instances to acquire information about each other to discover available clusters in order for your nodes to find the cluster to join.

The AWS-cloud plugin automatically handles the joining of a node into a cluster once a master is nominated.

setting a Discovery Permission as a policy and apply it to your IAM role should fix this. Here goes the policy I used:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "whatever",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeRegions",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeTags"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```